# Uninstalling Msi package with MSIEXEC

Tags: command-line, installation, windows-installer

I need to uninstall a MSI package through command line.
So i used:

msiexec /x package.msi

But this command requires the package.msi to be present in the local machine.

I want to uninstall the msi even if the msi file is missing.

How can I do that?

Comment: See here for a list of different ways to uninstall an MSI: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1055933/129130

Answer (score 16):

You can uninstall it using the product code:

```
msiexec.exe /x {your-product-code-guid}
```

You would obtain this code from the MSI itself, or whatever tool you are using to build the MSI.

Note that when you uninstall a product, it uses a cached MSI, since only the original MSI knows how to uninstall itself. When you use the product code, it uses the cached MSI from C:\WINDOWS\Installer.

Comment: what if you don't have the product id and it doesn't show up under "program and features" after you added the "product id" column?

Comment: Unfortunately, this still shows "Locate MSI file" dialog

Comment: **[How can I find the product GUID of an installed MSI setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup/29937569#29937569)**. Just in case you don't have the tools to view the MSI file itself.

Answer (score 7):

[**See my answer on stackoverflow.com**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1055933/129130) for various ways to uninstall MSI files / Windows Installer Packages from your computer.

> You can uninstall via: **msiexec**, **ARP**, **WMI**, **PowerShell**,
>   Deployment Systems such as **SCCM**, **VBScript** / COM Automation,
>   **DTF**, or via **hidden Windows cache folders**, and a few other options.